# How concatenate variable in url in magento

Tags: php, magento, url

I'm trying to add Variable in URL in magento. Here is my link:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper("html")->getUrl("admin/index/test/".$testId); ?>
```

If i add / at the end of profile then url not concatenate with testId. But if concatenate testId without adding / at the end of profile then it's not concatenate variable id. here is link

```
<?php echo Mage::helper("html")->getUrl("admin/index/test".$testId); ?>
```

Can anyone describe me, what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

#### There are a few mistakes:

- the first parameter to `getUrl` must be a *route* in the form `router/controller/action`. Additional parameters can be added with the second parameter
- the router for the `admin` URL is called `adminhtml`. Magento distinguishs between front name (the first part of the URL) and router (the internal value), which makes it possible to have a custom admin URL. This is configured in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml`:

  ```
  <routers>
      <adminhtml>
          <use>admin</use>
          <args>
              <module>Mage_Adminhtml</module>
              <frontName>admin</frontName>
          </args>
      </adminhtml>
  </routers>
  ```
- The last part(s) of a route can be ommitted in the URL if they are "index", so for the URL `/admin`, the route is `adminhtml/index/index`. But as soon as you want to add parameters, all parts are required, to distinguish the parameters from controller and action. It looks like you want to add the parameter `test=$testId` to the existing route `adminhtml/index/index`, which redirects to the configured start page, by default `adminhtml/dashboard/index`, or to the login page if you are not logged in.
- For admin URLs, you need to use the `adminhtml` helper (or the `adminhtml/url` model)

#### Conclusion

To get the URL `admin/index/index/test/$testId`, the first parameter must be `adminhtml/index/index` and the second parameter `['test' => $testId]`

```
echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/index/index", ['test' => $testId]);
```

#### Alternative

If you want to build the URL with GET parameters in the form `admin?test=$testId`, you can use the `_query` parameter:

```
echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/index/index",
    ['_query' => ['test' => $testId]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/index/index",array('test'=>$testId));
```